# R:Splitting and recombining a matrix

Tags: r, split

I am looking to split and recombine a matrix. The intention is to split each row over two rows, placing data from certain columns in the first row and data from other columns into the second row.

As an example:
The original matrix looks as follows:

> ```
> Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4    
> ABL  100  200  300    
> BGA  400  500  600  
> APN  700  800  900
> ```

I would like the new matrix to look like this:

> ```
> Col1 Col2 Col4  
> ABL1 100  300  
> ABL2 200  300  
> BGA1 400  600  
> BGA2 500  600  
> APN1 700  900  
> APN2 800  900
> ```

Where, in each case, I have split each row into two rows, with the first row containing the value from Col2 and the second row containing the value from Col3, and both containing the value from Col4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm quite stuck.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could help:

```
 DF <- read.table(text = "
        Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4    
        ABL  100  200  300    
        BGA  400  500  600  
        APN  700  800  900 ", header = T)

newDF <- cbind(as.character(DF$Col1), c(DF$Col2, DF$Col3), DF$Col4)

newDF <- as.data.frame(newDF[order(newDF[,1]),])

newDF$V1 <- paste(newDF$V1, 1:2, sep = "")

> newDF
    V1  V2  V3
1 ABL1 100 300
2 ABL2 200 300
3 APN1 700 900
4 APN2 800 900
5 BGA1 400 600
6 BGA2 500 600
```

But, the first column isn't sorted exactly as your data.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I wasn't concerned with the sorting of the data. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a loop, but I am sure there is a better answer.
if you got the data in my.data

```
  my.out.data<-data.frame()
for  (k in 1:nrow(my.data){
          assign(paste(c(row.names(my.data)[k],"1"), collapse=""),my.data[[k,c(1,3)]]) #Creates the first row of data
          assign(paste(c(row.names[k],"2"), collapse=""), my.data[[k,c(2,3)]]) #Creates the second row of data
             my.out.data<-rbind(get(paste(c(row.names[k],"1"), collapse="")),get(paste(c(row.names[k],"2"), collapse=""))) #Gets the rows inside the data
}
```

I haven't check it so it may contain some mistakes, but I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: You definitely do not need `assign` for this problem.

Comment: Why not? This way, without having created before the variable of each row I can link them the data. Or it works like that `paste(c(row.names(my.data)[k],"1"), collapse="")<-my.data[[k,c(1,3)]]` too?

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of @alexis_laz's solution:

```
out <- rbind(setNames(DF[,c(1,2,4)],c('Col1','Col2','Col4')),
             setNames(DF[,c(1,3,4)],c('Col1','Col2','Col4')))
out <- out[order(out$Col1),]
out$Col1 <- paste(out$Col1,1:2,sep='')
> out
  Col1 Col2 Col4
1 ABL1  100  300
4 ABL2  200  300
3 APN1  700  900
6 APN2  800  900
2 BGA1  400  600
5 BGA2  500  600
```